# How can I use a partition from a previous Windows installation on Linux as /home/<username>?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, fedora

I am switching from Windows to Linux Fedora and currently I'm configuring the partitions. I have already created `/boot` and `/` partitions. And I also have two partitions that I used with Windows: C (`/dev/sda2/` with Windows installed on it; I am going to delete it during Fedora installation) and D (`/dev/sda3` with some data). I don't want to create a separate `/home` because it is just waste of drive space and I would like to use the D drive as a `/home/<username>` instead.

How can I accomplish this? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Google( fedora move /home )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses `NTFS` file system which is proprietary. When you install Linux you'll probably choose `ext4` or some other file system. So in any case you'll have to format it if you want to set it as `home`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah, of course, I'm going to convert the filesystem from NTFS to EXT4, at least because NTFS will need defragmentation over time, and it will be necessary to defragment it from time to time. But to accomplish this, it's not necessary to format (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/140622/1086569)).

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about that software. I read the answer and understood that it copies content while formatting the free space in drive but what if there is no free space in the drive, in that case shrinking cannot be performed. However in certain rare situations this might be helpful. Thanks for sharing the information.